# jQuery .slideToggle works perfect in Chrome, not so perfect in Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, firefox

In this page: http://181.224.135.163/~tommasom/node/add/rapporto-di-lavoro, 
I added a .slideToggle when you choose "determinato".

The slide works both n Chrome and in Firefox but the div with this class

`.field-group-format-wrapper`

that is shown, makes a very little jump upward when finishing to open. Any tip?

Comment: You have to provide minimalistic code replicating issue in question itself

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery SlideToggle() Not Working in FireFox, Works in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855502/jquery-slidetoggle-not-working-in-firefox-works-in-chrome)

Comment: Hai un server decisamente lento :/

Comment: @Vixed: io mi trovo bene, ma accetto suggerimenti :D

Comment: @PonzioPilato non saprei cosa dire... cmq testata la answer?

Comment: @wrxsti: I added a .slideToggle to the div aforementioned, but in Firefox works strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using off() before on(), and it's working fine.
May be there are other listener on the same radio.
Check the code on your console:

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
jq.onload =function(){
    $("#edit-field-tempo-indeterminato-und").off().on('change',function(){
        $(".field-group-format-wrapper").slideToggle();
    });
};
```

Another strange stuff...

If I remove the margin-top from

```
.form-item,
.form-actions {
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

your code works good in firefox too.
so please try adding

```
#field-data-termine-add-more-wrapper>div{
    margin-top:0;
}
```

Comment: Resta cmq il fatto che hai un server lentissimo ed hai messo tonnellate di JS inutili.

Comment: It's the same, there's anyway the small jump upward. Yes I know, I need clean a bit, after it's all working!

Comment: @PonzioPilato I've tried this in Firefox adding off() before on(), and works perfectly. Can you please try doing the same? May be there are other listener on the same radio. **$("#edit-field-tempo-indeterminato-und").off().on('chan...**

Comment: I put the same your code but with my Firefox v44 (I'm on OSX) I can still see that little move upward that in Chrome and Safari doesn't exist...

Comment: Thanks! Margin top did the trick! You're invited for a beer in Bologna ;)

Comment: Thanks! I will come ;) @PonzioPilato

Comment: @PonzioPilato ... can you please check my answer if it's correct?

Comment: Done! I don't understand why they voted down my question as it is different by the other one...